# MomentJS warning in Vue app after importing it from webpack

Tags: javascript, vue.js, webpack, momentjs

After searching for a little while, I saw all the posts regarding this warning were caused when using MomentJS, but in my case, this warning is being shown after importing it on my main.js file without even starting to use it for the first time, i haven't even added a "new Date()" nor any moment call in any part of my code yet.

This is the whole warning I'm getting:

```
Deprecation warning: value provided is not in a recognized RFC2822 or ISO format. moment construction falls back to js Date(), which is not reliable across all browsers and versions. Non RFC2822/ISO date formats are discouraged and will be removed in an upcoming major release. Please refer to http://momentjs.com/guides/#/warnings/js-date/ for more info.
Arguments: 
[0] _isAMomentObject: true, _isUTC: false, _useUTC: false, _l: undefined, _i: function Vue (options) {
  if ("development" !== 'production' &&
    !(this instanceof Vue)
  ) {
    warn('Vue is a constructor and should be called with the `new` keyword');
  }
  this._init(options);
}, _f: undefined, _strict: undefined, _locale: [object Object]
Error
    at Function.eval [as createFromInputFallback] (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/moment/moment.js:320:98)
    at configFromInput (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/moment/moment.js:2606:19)
    at prepareConfig (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/moment/moment.js:2577:13)
    at createFromConfig (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/moment/moment.js:2544:44)
    at createLocalOrUTC (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/moment/moment.js:2631:16)
    at createLocal (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/moment/moment.js:2635:16)
    at hooks (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/moment/moment.js:12:29)
    at Function.Vue.use (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/vue/dist/vue.esm.js:4850:14)
    at eval (webpack-internal:///./src/main.js:51:46)
    at Object../src/main.js (http://localhost:8080/app.js:14037:1)
```

The way I added momentJS in my project was by running:

`npm i moment -D`

Then in main.js I have the following:

```
import * as Moment from 'moment'

Vue.use(Moment)

window.app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    router: Router,
    store: store,
    render: h => h(App)
})
```

I know it's a warning but it's kinda annoying to have it at every page refresh. Would be nice to avoid it.

Any clues? Thanks in advance.

Comment: `Vue.use(Moment)` does execute code though. You can even see in your stacktrace: `at Function.Vue.use`

Answer (score 3):

You probably don't want to pass `moment` to `Vue.use()`. `use()` will treat that like a plugin (as documented [here](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#Vue-use)) and try to call it while passing `Vue` as an argument, which of course `moment` won't underatand. This is most likely why you are getting that error. If you want a Vue moment plugin there's [one here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-moment). If you just want `moment`, there's no reason to pass it to `use`.

Comment: Ohh, i see... and what do you suggest if I want to have it global? do like a window.moment = require('moment')?

Comment: Mmm i really like the idea of "vue-moment", i'm already using "vue-awesome" which is a font-awesome plugin for vue. Thanks!

Comment: The Vue docs have an [example](https://vuejs.org/v2/cookbook/adding-instance-properties.html#Real-World-Example-Replacing-Vue-Resource-with-Axios) of adding axios to the `Vue.prototype` to gain universal access. Not sure how widely this used for other things.

Comment: No prob! I ended up installing vue-moment! :) I need moment for nothing too complex so i'm fine it if has the basic stuff at least! I will check it as answer whenever possible. Thanks again!